# Different target in pom.xml files

Tags: java, android, maven

I am building an android app and I am trying to use external libraries (jar).
When I build project it throws

> bad class file magic or version

I checked pom.xml files and I noticed that in the one jar it has the following

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

while in the other

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Could this justify the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because You can't use Java8 code in java7 project.

Comment: Does this code in pom.xml file means that java 8 is targeted and since this is an android project it is not allowed?

Comment: Looks like the first pom file is building for java 8.

Comment: @eric The problem here is that Android does not support 8 or that different versions are used? Thanks!

Comment: Some quick googling makes me think that this specific error is related to android. That said, you could definitely have issues bringing in a jar that uses 1.8 features into a 1.7 project. The other way is typically ok, the jdk can run older versions of java just fine, but obviously an older version couldn't run something built for a newer version. Sorry, I have experience with maven and java, but not so much with android.